# each_pair and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to loop through an unknown set of attributes and build a edit form
and I am not understanding clearly the way form_for works, and the syntax required.

trying to do something like this:

```
  - @thing.attributes.each_pair do |name, value|
    = f.label name
    = f.text_field value
```

while the label part works, the actual text_field does not

Comment: Please describe what aspect is "not working."  Is it not displaying at all, not populating, throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text_field` should be passed the name of the field rather than the current value so needs to be

```
f.text_field name
```

See the example at the top of this page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Rails will pick up the current value of the field from the object that you've passed to `form_for` so it doesn't need to be one of the parameters to `text_field`.

Comment: this was it.. sometime the answer is right in front of you.. just could not see it.  thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you're dynamically generating a form like this you should also look in the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and check out the `content_columns` method (as an alternative to `attributes`) and the `humanize` method (which can generate nicer labels for you e.g. `f.label name.humanize`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- @thing.attributes.each_pair do |name, value|
    = f.label name
    = f.text_field name.to_sym, value
```